# how to repeat get request every values change

Tags: node.js

I have codes like

```
app.post('/zamansecimi',(req,res)=>{


{
    zamansecimim(req.body.baslangic,req.body.bitis)

  
  res.render('./dist/rapor.ejs')
}});


function zamansecimim (bas,bit) {
 
app.get("/zamansecimi2", function (req, res) {
  
 
data2="select * from raporlama where oncekizaman between $1 and $2"
  var query = connection2.query(data2,[bas,bit] ,

 
  function(err, result) {
  if(err) throw err;

  
res.send(httpResponse(result.rows));
         });
  })
}
```

In these codes I want to change get result every post request but I have a problem with get request these values never change when I send to 2 or 3 ...request. First request is working.
Where is my mistake?

thank you for your help

Comment: The code is unreadable. Please reformat it correctly.

Comment: I have edited...

Comment: Even after "formatting" it is still terrible to read. The code quality is poor - unused variables `bas` and `bit` and useless extra braces in the top function, lack of semicolons to end lines, `data2` is not declared and so on. But these issues aside, you have structured the express app incorrectly. You should not be putting the route declaration (`app.get("/zamansecimi2", function (req, res)...`) inside the function `zamansecimim`. That makes no sense. Also, if you are posting data, where are you adding that data to the table `oncekizaman` ?

Comment: I want to select date from post request and send to this date get request to render data table.so I used function to get every datatable request correctly.data2 isn't declared because it is a postgresql query

Comment: `data2` is a variable, but there's no `var`, `let` or `const` before it.

Comment: A post request should be used for adding new data, not for a query. Thats is a GET's job.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you're trying to send back two different responses to the same request. Why do you need `res.render('./dist/rapor.ejs')`?

Comment: I need it because I have two pages one of the pages is I select date and the other one I listed a table according to the selected date

Answer (score 0):

Each request sent to the server can only have one response, and you can't trigger a GET request inside a POST request on the server and expect the response to that request to go back to the browser. Without the whole app, I can't tell you the best way to do what you want, but I'd suggest you have one response on the server like this:

```
app.post('/zamansecimi',(req, res)=>{
  const bas = req.body.baslangic;
  const bit = req.body.bitis;
  const query="select * from raporlama where oncekizaman between $1 and $2";
  connection2.query(query,[bas,bit], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(httpResponse(result.rows));
  });
});
```

That will at least ensure you get the correct data back to the browser. It does not seem to me like `rapor.ejs` needs re-rendering since nothing has changed on the server with the POST request. But honestly I can't tell what's going on from the code provided.

Comment: I know. But there's not enough context provided to satisfy you, sorry. What I can tell you is that your express app is malformed and won't work. You must restructure with one request and response per route.